# Is tipping mandatory at Restaurants and Bars in Germany?

Tags: europe, germany, restaurants, tipping, bavaria

In Bavaria, I paid for my drink, I asked her for "Ruckgeld", but only got the integer part of the money back, the rest of it, she kept it for tip! I looked her in the eye and she understood that I wasn't happy with that "initiative", but wouldn't blink an eye!

My company advised me to let it go, mentioning that if I was going to ask for the change, she would swear.

Notice how she didn't return me the correct amount back and then stare at me, demanding for tip, but she would decide for me!

Since, I will be around for a week or so, I was thinking of paying the exact amount of money next time. Will I get in an uncomfortable situation of having the waiter stare at me, demanding a tip? In other words, is *tipping* mandatory in Germany?

---

<sub>PS: Having experienced the tipping-cruelty in USA, and having tipped generously waiters across the Mediterranean for their supreme behavior, this Saturday night came as a shock, since I had the impression that this awful habit was only a USA-thing (you know, just like the fake audience laughing they have in USA TV series :) ).</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85090/discussion-on-question-by-gsamaras-is-tipping-mandatory-at-restaurants-and-bars).

Comment: One important point I think is that you'd normally say the amount to tip prior to handing over the money. Therefore when you didn't say anything the waiter would be understandably unhappy. Still tipping is not required since Germany does have minimum wages, but it's to be expected unless you look very young etc.

Comment: Did you go to a fairly touristy place and did she recognise you as a foreigner? I have never experienced nor heard of something like that. As @cbeleites points out in their answer, this would be considered as totally unacceptable behaviour by locals.

Comment: Tipping cruelty?

Comment: Please @copper.hat, read the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85090/discussion-on-question-by-gsamaras-is-tipping-mandatory-at-restaurants-and-bars), already discussed. :)

Comment: No. It’s recommended, the usual amount is 3% to 6% (not 10%, that’s American), and you usually just round numbers up. (My rule of thumb is, 25¢ for every begun 5€, which is in the 3–6% range.) It’s acceptable to not tip, e.g. when short on money, but also when dissatisfied.

Comment: I didn't get the last part of your comment @mirabilos. But I think I got the idea about the percentage, thanks!

Comment: I live in Bavaria, and usually do tip -- stating the full amount I want to pay as a round number.  BUT when I lived in San Francisco, whenever I ordered pizza delivered, the same thing happened to me there -- the driver would return the integer part of my change and keep the rest.  (I would have tipped **even more** if they had given me all my change first.)  So I would stop ordering from that place.  But they all did the same thing, so eventually I wasn't ordering delivered pizza any more.  And food service personnel know how to hurt with just a glance; I would suggest just staring them down.

Comment: @Jennifer good tip, thanks, from a person who was in SF as well! ;)

Comment: Any time tipping is mandatory or even expected, it stops being a tip.

Comment: Exactly @Spudley. Many seem to forget the meaning of the tip.

Comment: As a Scotsman, I must play into the added stereotype that the Germans have created for us: mean & decidedly money-pinching.  I am therefore *obligated* to not tip.  I have a reputation to maintain.

Comment: A lot of 'USA'-things get spread around the world. Effective wages have been in decline for quite a while, and so there are a lot of places where the staff actually does depend on tips here, as well. Personally, I try to assess the location I'm in to see whether or not I will tip (I have little money, if I had more, I'd probably assess the location to come up with an idea of how much to tip).

Comment: @gsamaras I am German and used to live in Munich until recently. Only in Munich have I ever experienced rude waitresses (yes, only female...). We once wanted to tip a waitress with a fairly large amount of coins and she outright yelled at us to keep "our shit to ourselves". We never went to that place again (Loewenbraeukeller). What I want to say, is that it is unfortunate that this badly behaving waitress made you think about tipping in general in Germany.

Comment: @Sebastian I agree, my second visit to a bar in Munich was a much better experience (not then why in the world would she ask me if I want water in my non-concentrated Apple juice is another story :) ).

Comment: @gsamaras It's called Schorle and it's a thing!

Comment: Waitresses don't want to carry around copper coins: lots of weight - no value. That simple

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Tipping is not at all mandatory in Germany and usually the service personnel does not rely on tips as much as in the USA, say. Usually, if you do not state the amount you want to round up to ("make it X EUR" — or "Stimmt so" if you do not expect change at all), they will start picking up coins from their purse and give you the exact amount of change without even a frown. Nevertheless, they sometimes do this search for coins suitably slowly to give you the opportunity to correct your forgetfulness by specifying your tip while they are searching or by simply not picking up all the change.

That being said, rounding up by approximately 5% up to 10% (or to the next or second next full Euro for small amounts) is overwhelmingly common for most types of Restaurant unless you were quite dissatisfied.

Comment: +1 This is my experience as well. To back it up even more, here is a video by EasyGerman asking people on the street in Germany how to tipp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BPZXUon3Qw

Comment: One additional point it is worth making: you give the tip directly to the server, you do *not* leave it on the table (which is the norm in the UK).

Comment: Make sure that, if you tip, you round up to full Euros making it easier for the waiter to find your change, especially in a busy place. If your bill is 4€90, and you hand the waiter a 10€ bill saying "make this 5€20", you'll come across as incredibly rude.

Comment: While your answer is technically 100% correct, it should be pointed out that tipping is _de facto_ mandatory insofar as the Finanzamt will boldly allege that waiters have so-and-so-much tip and have them pay income tax for that, whether they ever get that money or not. So if you don't tip, you're not just not-paying, but basically taking money away from them. Though a default tip of 10% seems a bit steep, I'd do 2-3 Euros for a typical lunch, and maybe an Euro or less (just rounding to full Euro) when having a few beers.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Though that's exactly the kind of situation where I tend to tip by first waiting for the exact change to be returned, to hand over a (previously prepared) set of coins afterwards.

Comment: @Damon: The "Gesetz zur Steuerfreistellung von Arbeitnehmertrinkgeld" (BGBl. I 2002 S. 3111) tells otherwise. Waiters do *not* have to pay taxes for any money *that is directly handed to them by third persons independently of their regular income* and *without legal claim*, i.e. *voluntarily*. Regardless of the amount of tips (they may triple your regular income). See also the thereby changed §3 Nr. 51 EStG (since 2002). This also (legally) defines tips as a voluntary thing for Germany.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Incredibly rude is a strong statement. It might be seen as not worth the effort, but still better than leaving no tip. And since I don't think leaving no tip is not seen as incredibly rude. Although it is true, that you might as well not tip trivial amounts, like less than 0,50€, if you are not rounding up to a full Euro.

Comment: The normal amount should be 3–6%, but everything else listed here, including just “stimmt so” and not making the waiter hand out small money back (give him a 10€ bill and 20¢ if you want to give 5.20€) is superb.

Answer (score 68):

### TL;DR

- Tipping is **never mandatory**, but most Germans do it.
- **5%-10%** is most common, **round up** to a whole number, or to 50 ct if amount < 10€
- Not tipping does not automatically mean that you were unsatisfied, but could be a hint.

### Should I tip?

In general, deciding whether or how much to tip is a subject of debate in Germany as well, just as in many other countries. But while non-tipping people are weird in the US, this is not the case in Germany.

Most people do tip, so that is "the norm", and often more than would be required, to avoid appearing stingy. But this tells you that its more about the perception by other people not because the servers need it. Nobody will approach you and ask what's wrong, if you don't tip.

Of course tips can make up a substantial part of the servers earnings but they are not vital, like in the US.

### How much?

5%-10% is commonly accepted rate but can be raised to 15%. The most important factor is to **make the amount a whole number** by rounding it up. For low amounts below 10€ you can also round up (after tip) to the nearest 50ct.

If the bill says 16,60 €, you would pay 18 €, if you think the service was really good or you don't care about money you could do 19 €. Giving 20 € might come accross as showing off or trying to impress the (female) server. So don't overdo it.

### What to say?

- If you don't say anything and just hand the server your money, they should give you the change to the cent. If they don't, this would be very rude and worth a complaint.
- If you want to tip, you just say the desired amount while you are handing him the money, e.g. *Achtzehn, bitte*. So, simply the amount followed by a "*Bitte*". He will give you change for the amount specified by you.
- If you have the desired amount handy, you just give him the 18 € and say "*Stimmt so!*" which informs the server that this is the correct amount you want to give and he does not have to give you anything back.

### Why rounding up?

The tip is not seen as charity but serves to ease the transaction while also complimenting the person that took care of you.

Servers in Germany are not except from minimal wage and we have social security. You'll never be hungry or have no place to live if you don't work. Therefore, we do not feel that we need to contribute something to the servers wage. The tip is considered an extra.

Rounding up, eases the payment (less change to keep in your pocket + less math to do in your head) and serves as a "front" for the tip. It does not serve to secure the "survival" of the server, you are merely "to lazy" to do the math and don't mind giving a little extra while you are it.

Of course not everyone thinks about this with this much detail, but imho, this is the generalized German attitude towards tipping.

Comment: Showing off?  Man i tip too high then

Comment: @JonH: Be assured that you never made a waiter unhappy by tipping them too much :-)

Comment: "Not tipping does not mean that you were unsatisfied" - I think this claim is incorrect. Not tipping here in Germany is a bit of a slap in the face of the waiter. It is true that "[n]o-one will approach you and ask what's wrong, if you don't tip", but that is more of a saving-face thing ("the customer has expressed extreme dissatisfaction with the service by not tipping, let's not make things even more awkward for everyone involved by making this a topic of conversation") than with not tipping not sending a strong message. At least, that's the way it's handled in South-West Germany.

Comment: In my city (in the North, lots of students) if you don't tip and look young enough, people will assume you're a student on a budget. The benefit of the doubt is also given to anyone not obviously well off as long as it isn't a high end restaurant. Also, it's common for waiters to ask whether you were satisfied before brining the bill - so tipping is definitely not the only way to express your satisfaction.

Comment: "to avoid doing the math" No, I do it to avoid having loads of little coins in my purse.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I have a minor nitpick: When giving a tip of 10% on a bill of 16,60€, this would be 18,26€. Thus, when rounding up as this answer implies, you should pay 19€. That said, I find rounding down slightly acceptable. You could also just edit your example to a bill of 16,20€ to avoid this situation.

Comment: the usual tip in germany is 5% to 10%, as you do no exact calculation by rounding to a full number you might give little more (14,20€ + 10% = 15,62€ -> 16€, which makes 12,7% tip), but doing this with a start of 15% or even 20% is very unusual and looks wired - so probably no waiter would complain.

Comment: I agree with O. R. Mapper, this answer at least doesn't cover all of Germany, here in Munich not tipping at all would be considered a clear sign of dissatisaction.

Comment: @JohannesDorn You are "rounding up" the €16,60, not the €18,26.

Comment: About "What to say": if you speak some German, I asked that very question some time ago: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29256/wie-kann-man-dem-kellner-sagen-wieviel-trinkgeld-man-ihm-gibt

Comment: The typical amount for tipping indeed is closer to 5% than 10%, unless it's a single drink, where you would often round up to the closest multiple of 50 cents.  If I only have a coffee for say, 2.40 EUR, I wouldn't tip if all they did was bring me the drink. For your example of 16.60 EUR, I would probably tip 17.50 EUR if I was satisfied, or nothing if they got the order wrong, were slow, unfriendly or didn't remember who in my small party got which drink.Source: I grew up with a restaurant, worked as a waiter many years and have lived in several different German cities.

Comment: I like this answer, except for the reasoning. Tipping well is not an indicator that you are rich or that you feel the waiter/waitress needs charity. A good tip is appeciated anywhere, especially if you were satisfied and had a nice lunch/dinner/coffee. It is also not common to "hide" the tip. Some people may be insecure about tipping too little or too much, but IMO there is no need to be. When tipping well, I never had the feeling that I was being "lavish". When not tipping (for small bills) I also never had the feeling of being cheap.

Comment: A generous tip would usually not be disrespectful at all if you make it clear you are generous because the service was awesome.

Comment: Suggested addition to the second paragraph below "how much", after "how rich you are": If you give 17, you might be perceived as even more stingy than if you gave the exact amount.

Comment: "Why rounding up" is a very astute observation. As a native German, I thinks this really hits the nail on the head. For the same reason, it's perfectly possible to tip too much in Germany.

Comment: As for your final paragraphs, I like that - for small transactions (e.g. a pint in a pub) that's pretty much spot on for the UK as well. We say "keep the change" almost with a sigh as if we just can't be bothered to deal with silly little bits of copper, when in reality we've obviously made a conscious decision to let the establishment keep them.

Comment: You're overtipping to the point people will check if you peed on the carpet and want to make up for it.

Comment: Tipping isn't legally mandatory, but it is generally  _socially_ mandatory in Germany where you get table service (unless obviously the service was really bad).  Note for many people working in bars and gastro, tips make a large % of the take-home pay and makes the difference between being able to live from the pay or not.

Comment: "`10%-15% is most common`" - have you ever been in Germany?

Comment: @Mawg: Somewhat, I have lived here for 26 years, but other than that, no.

Comment: Lolx! I only spent twelve or thirteen years there myself, and in my experience the locals just round up to the nearest Euro or two max, even on quite large restaurant bills.

Comment: @Pete: Socially mandatory, yes. Because it is a way of saying "thak you", which is considered just general politeness. But I cannot subscribe to factoring the question how dependent on the tip staff are into the decision on whether or how much to tip. As a customer, my contract is with the establishment, and the contract is about getting a service in return for paying x €. These x € should cover all expenses for the establishment to carry out the service (which include paying their employees). If the establishment then advertises they offer the same service for y € (with y < x), while ...

Comment: ... implicitly expecting me to pay x - y € directly to the staff, this rings all kinds of alarm bells for me, including tax evasion and fraudulent deception on the actual price for the service. Therefore, if I get the impression the staff actually *depends* on the tips, I would not tip at all, as the tip stops being a mere "thank you" and becomes financial support to maintain a borderline(?)-criminal scheme instead.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It is the social norm. "When in Rome...".
According to studies, Germans still tip even if not totally satisfied with the service.
Whilst Germany has a minimum wage, tips are a recognition of the hard work involved, and yes, politeness.
Also, tips are tax free (§ 3 Nr. 51 EStG). Please do a little research before accusing thousands of people of tax evasion (serious offence in Germany).

Comment: @Pete: I know. I am German, and I live in Germany. I always tip, unless I feel tipping is *expected*, as in "if I don't tip, the staff do not have enough money from their regular job payments". In this latter situation, I have to assume the establishment is trying to defraud me by charging hidden cost (i.e. charging x € on the menu, but actually charging y € because they expect me to hand over y - x € directly to the staff). And that is exactly why it *is* a form of tax evasion, as a part of the establishment's revenue - a part that they should use to pay their employees - circumvents ...

Comment: ... taxation by going directly from customer to employee as a tax-free tip.

Answer (score 26):

Others have explained how tipping works normally in Germany.

I'd like to add that what you describe would certainly be a reason for me to not tip at all, i.e. insist on my full change: refusing the correct change is just totally outside acceptable behaviour for a waiter.

And by the way, it is less usual but not unheard of to first get the full change and then hand over the tip.
This is similar to how tipping is done in small bakeries or at the village butcher's: they have a separate box for tips (or sometimes for donations to some other cause): the official cash register is for the exact price (and has to be correct to the cent), everything else has to go somewhere else. For waiters coming to the table it is too inconvenient to have 2 purses, but already the bar at the local sports club may have the cash box for sold goods/drinks and a separate tip box (typically donations to the kids/youth section)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the really rude and uncommon behaviour of the waitress.

Comment: Right. In fact I've encounters waiters who tried to give back change even when the amount I gave suggested clearly I wanted to tipp, something like 19,00 € → given 21,00 → tried giving back a 2 € coin...

Comment: I'd suggest that many Germans who work in bars and similar are getting irritated by tourists who don't tip when it's generally socially expected to because the tourists didn't bother doing their homework before traveling.

Comment: @Pete: While I think your observation is true, IMHO that irritation is still no reason to refuse giving the full change. In fact, I don't think there's any valid excuse for not giving change short of that tip in question having been promised before. In addition, in the encounter described by OP, the waitress did not yet have (IHMO) any valid reason for such an irritation: she can *know* that she didn't get any tip only after the guests leave with their full change. The usual German way of indicating rounding up requires rather advanced command of the German language - which is more than the...

Comment: ... homework I think one can expect from a tourist. IMHO both leaving tip on the table when going and handing over the tip from the change (as a 2nd transaction after paying) are totally acceptable ways of tipping. Both include the waitress handing over the change. And this IMHO *has to be* the automatic reaction if no tip is expressed within the second-ish timeframe when paying when we usually do this. BTW: I know several foreigners who had done their homework about tipping but nevertheless were to shy to try the rounding-up way and decided to hand over the tip separately.

Answer (score 18):

Tipping is generally never mandatory in Germany, but the general etiquette is:

- Restaurants and bars where they bring you food and drink to the table: **Yes**
- Restaurants where you carry your food to the table yourself: **No**
- Bars where you carry your drink to the table yourself: **Optional**, but doing so can improve quality of service if you want another drink later.
- Food delivery services: **Yes**, unless they are late.
- Retail: **No**, but they sometimes collect change for charity. Participation is optional.
- Cab drivers: **Optional**
- Tour guides: **Optional**, when they ask for it
- Street performers: **Optional**, when you like them and they placed some container in front of them to throw change into. Do not give money to people who perform in a place where it is explicitly forbidden, like on a train for example. Do not enable rule breakers!
- Any government employee: **Gets you arrested for attempted bribery**

As other answers have pointed out, you usually tip by rounding the bill up to an even sum.

Comment: "Music in public transport: depends: if stationary (in buildings, at entrance) optional; self performed AND high quality (playing guitar for example) in trains/subway/etc: optional; low quality, loud or even electronic supported (more loud): NEVER" - add to the list since lots of people arrive at the airport and its the first "steal-from-tourists"-thing they may encounter (also the spots at public transport buildings normally are paid for by the artist via day license), while in most cities its not allowed to perform in carriages, tipping the ones that don't play by the rules: more than unfair

Comment: @user2567875 quality is subjective, but my recent edit should cover most of this.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the difference between getting table service (drinks brought to you, you should tip) and self-service (you collect the drinks, tipping nice but not so expected)

Answer (score 12):

The behaviour of the waitress described is highly unusual for Germany. Were you at Oktoberfest or some other tourist trap location?

Tipping in Germany is not mandatory, though it is very common to round up for an effective tip around 10%. Note that we don't go by percents, we go by convenience. So if your bill is 28.30 Euros, you would typically give 30 and say "stimmt so" (which means roughly "fits like this", and indication that you don't expect change). If the bill is 29.60 Euros, you would typically give 30 plus a one or two Euro coin. We would never calculate exactly 10% and then add that.

However, I have only once in my entire life had a waiter or waitress not return exact change if not explicitly told "stimmt so" or something similar.

You absolutely do have a right to pay the exact amount on the bill, and a service person should not make a fuss about it. While tipping is highly common (almost everyone at least rounds up), if a waitress did not return me change upon me asking for it (your "Rückgeld"), I would ask for the manager.

Answer (score 8):

How much one tips also depends on the place; more in a restaurant where one sat at a table, less for takeout food, probably nothing in a bakery where one buys bread rolls. It is certainly possible to specify the tip when one hands over the money, as in "make it €15" when the bill says €14.20 (which would be on the stingy side).

In the example given above, €14.20, handing over €17 would imply that one intendeds it as tip, otherwise one would have given €15 ...

Answer (score 7):

I usually round up to the next Euro when under €10, to the next second or third Euro when under €25-30. After that approx. 10% but not more than €5 except service was extraordinary and outstanding.

If the service is below average (or prices are not reasonable), I don't tip since tip is actually already included in the price in Germany and Switzerland.

Answer (score 3):

10% is the usual amount. But if you have cash, what you usually do is take the amount, and round it up. If your bill is €24.30, you leave €27 which is very close to 10%. If it is €24.90, you will see people thinking: Should I give €27 which is tight or €28 which is more generous?

Obviously more or less if the service was very good or very bad. No tip doesn't mean "not completely satisfied", it means it was so bad that you will never, ever come back. (I think I've done that once, when a friend and I ordered the same meal, and the bill was for 2x price of two meals = 4 meals instead of two).

Comment: You should have stated that, and I am pretty sure they would correct it, it is very likely that this was a mistake. Thanks for the info, +1, rounding up seems ridiculous to me, but I guess when in Rome ....

Comment: Well, if I hadn't noticed it it would have been a mistake that was rather expensive for me. "If I hadn't watched out the bill would have been €30 more" means "no tip".

Comment: `it means it was so bad that you will never, ever come back` This simply not true. In Germany it is not uncommon to not tip at all and this does not mean what you are impying. Yes, it more common to tip but not tipping doesn't have the same severity it does in the US.

Comment: ah @gsamaras when in rome, prepare to pay through the teeth!.

Comment: @gsamaras: See my answer for why we round up. It's imho a matter of respect, because you would only give charity to beggars.

Comment: Upvoted for the second paragraph, even though I think the numbers given in the first are higher than what is actually usual.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in Bavarian we do not say "stimmt so", but we say "des basst a-so" or "des basst scho" or something alike "mach'ma 18", when rounding up to integer values (please don't ask me to explain the grammar of this assumed "we" form). There's even places, where they refuse the accept the rounded value - but return to the cent, no matter what you tell them (always depending on their policy).

If someone takes his/her own tip, this is highly incorrect and this place should better be avoided. the proper response might be "es Kratler", which roughly translates to "you punks". Bavarian is Daytsh, alike Yiddish is... that's why it tends to foul language, especially when it comes to incorrectness.

That would at least be a statement, which would communicate, that you're not a tourist.

Because: such scammers do assume, to see you once only and then never again.

Demanding to see the manager is not common for small amounts; but future avoidance is.

If wanting to argue, then demand the full change first and then leave them 10 cents as tip (as insult).

Which also implies, that tiny tips might be understood that way, in general.

As a rule of thumb, don't over-do it and don't under-do it. It should be fair, depending on the occasion, the amount of people which had been served (both important factors in gastronomy, which had not yet been stated) and the overall amount which had been charged, multiplied by the service quality provided (in a range from 0 to 1.5). Giving no tip at all is less likely to be understood as an insult, but when tipping a tiny amount, they might ask you what was wrong with the food or service (responding with an insult of a tip, to an insulting service-quality level); basically, that's a non-verbal inquiry for a service-quality suggestion to be asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The waitress was being substantially rude to you and I don’t understand your company advising you to let it be (were they non-German?). The correct answer to her would have been ‘*x* cents are missing’ (in German: ‘Da fehlen *x* cent.’) with a mildly angry tone in your voice.

While tipping is common in restaurants in Germany it is not mandatory and it is always seen as something nice you do voluntarily. Waitors may give you ample opportunity to decide on a tip, e.g. slowly ‘searching’ for coins in the purse (it might as well just be shuffling around) but barring any statement from the customer exact change is to be given (and you should not have to ask for it).

If I were to witness such a behaviour even if not directed to myself, I would remove whatever I had intended to tip from the bill.

Comment: Non German company, indeed, logical answer Jan, thanks! PS: Nice hat:)

Answer (score 0):

In Germany, not leaving any tip is telling you weren't satisfied with the service. You may do this, but it's very rude if you also tell in words you were satisfied.

The most common practice is to tip around 5%. Small orders 10%.

Comment: This is wrong. Not leaving a tip is not communicating that you aren't satisifed, at all.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The default is for the wait staff to return the money to the cent. It is then up to the customer to decide. Yes, it is common to tip (and even more common to skip this process and inform the wait staff how big the tip is before they return the money) but it wouldn't be out of the ordinary for someone to only pay the actual amount charged.

Comment: Definitely wrong. You *only* leave a tip if you were *above* satisfied.

Comment: This is wrong. Tips are totally optional.

Comment: German from South-Western Germany here: I think this answer is correct. Not tipping is like expressing "Service by everyone involved, especially the waiter, was abysmal." At the same time, numbers like 15% stated in other answers seem way over the top to me. When I'm charged 25€, for instance, a total payment of 26€ (i.e. 1€ as a tip) is completely appropriate in my experience.

Comment: Looks like there are some regional differences here. I'm from Munich and I definitely agree with Janka. If you don't at least round up to the next euro it is a clear sign that you considered the service subpar.

Comment: south-western contradicting the previous two comments: that interpretation is not even regionally universal. even within the south, some people are very convinced no tip implies dissatisfaction while others see it the way the previous comments did. I'd like to throw in that the setting of the meal (eating out because you have no food at home vs. meal as a social "event" like meeting friends) might a larger role than the satisfaction.