# How much should I tip in restaurants in Germany?

Tags: germany, tipping

There is already a question about [whether tips are mandatory in Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124708/is-tipping-mandatory-at-restaurants-and-bars-in-germany/124731), but **how much** should I tip?

Comment: While answering and extending my answer to the linked question I thought about the exact percentage. I then realized that this information is off-topic to the linked question, because it does not ask "how much" but "whether". I have more content that want to provide and it feels like this does not belong in my original answer. I think the popularity of the topic warrants a dedicated question.

Comment: While the other question did not ask for how much, it has several good answers that indicate the amounts or percentages.

Comment: Is it not in the interest of the site to have answers that specifically answer the quesiton asked? Having anwers specific to the quesiton makes finding answers easier. If I only see the title of the linked question it is not evident that I will find an answer to "how much". Taking your view to the extreme, we would to have "blog" type answers that cover everything that is vaguely related to the question and are a chore to read through.

Comment: And as you can see from the answers and discussions around them in the other question, the tipping amount is very much opinion based. Having actually worked on the receiving end of tips and not just giving, I would say that anything between 0 and 20% is common and that it is quite common not to tip, even if service has been satisfactory.

Comment: @Willeke, one might edit the title of the not-quite-duplicate question, but then the title no longer matches the question. I don't think that a question is a duplicate just because the answer is the same ...

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, I was in the process of writing an answer to explain *how* to tip, "Stimmt so" or "auf *whatever*". I thought it worthwhile, or I wouldn't have started.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion I was hasty in closing, (I still stand by that the other question covers all that this question asks about) but I have joined the re-open votes.

Comment: @o.m. The question is however not *how* to tip, but *how much* to tip and that is IMHO opinion based. I have voted to close the question. There has been enough discussions around alleged appropriate tipping amounts in the other question. No need to repeat the entire discussion here as well.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: partly relevant: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4849/is-it-ok-to-have-the-same-content-in-two-different-answers-even-if-it-is-releva

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, this was closed, reopened, and now there is one close vote again. I think I'll wait how the consensus on that develops, not voting again on open/close, and improve my answer re regional specifics if they pop up in comments.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I've edited it to be about how much people typically tip. That doesn't seem to be opinion-based, to me: how much any specific person should tip in any specific situation is entirely their opinion, but the behaviour of the population at large is not.

Comment: @DavidRicherby With that edit, you have changed the meaning of the question, so that neither of the two current answers fit. I am also not sure how you know that it is what problemofficer actually ment to ask. Likely it is not, since he wrote one of the answers himself and tried to answer what he originally asked. And to nitpick: The title and the body of the question is now in mismatch.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I solved the nitpick part by editing the title, since that was easy. As to the substantive part of your comment, IMO, it's better to have an on-topic answerable question with not-great answers than a closed off-topic question. If the asker insists that the question must be "How much should I tip?" then the question will be closed and nobody gains anything. If they are willing to compromise on the wording, then the question can presumably stay open, with the possibility that somebody will contribute a researched, objective answer (e.g., "This survey says Germans tip 12.7%").

Comment: I think the original question, "How much should I tip?", is on topic, because it's a legitimate question for a traveller, and a useful one. The fact that there is no clear rule or consensus should be the answer (or maybe part of one), not a reason for closing it. So I would propose to roll the question back to its first revision, to leave it open, and to have someone, possibly a local (@Tor-EinarJarnbjo, maybe?) post that there is no general agreement on this.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It is IMHO bad conduct to edit a question substantially, so that the meaning is changed. At least when there are answers to the original text of the question. If you agree that this question is off-topic, but a variant is not, then let this question be closed and ask the other question in a new post. See also 'when to edit' in the help center ('clarify the meaning... without changing that meaning'): https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Seriously, what practical difference do you think there is between "how much should I tip?" and "how much do people usually tip?" Why is the answer to the former not "You should tip what people normally tip, which is XYZ"? Why do you feel that adhering to these procedures is more important than getting good answers to good questions. What is the point of closing a question with answers and demanding that it be asked again in a slightly different way?

Comment: @DavidRicherby It was *your* point that you actually changed the question and not that you asked the same in a different way. Asking for how much people usually tip can only be answered if you find a survey or statistics on this topic. Asking how much one *should* tip is something completely different and the IMHO only right answer to that question is 'whatever *you* feel the service was worth more than what's already at the bill'. Noone is in Germany expected to tip a certain amount only because it is mathematically possible to calculate the average tip.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Let us continue the discussion on meta: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/changing-the-meaning-of-a-question

Answer (score 4):

### How much ?

In general, **tipping is optional** in Germany. While not tipping is not the typical case, there are people who don't tip at all. Thus it does not necessarily imply that something bad happened. It is different from the US, where you can expect the manager to ask you what kind of catastrophy the server has caused.

It is **hard to give a universal percentage** that is always applicable because you usually round up to the next 50 ct for low amounts and to the next euro for higher amounts. You would also probably avoid paying 89€ and round it to 90€.

I "crunched some numbers" and found that **5%-10%** is a good approximation of a common tip percentage. Marked in green are values in columns that felt right. There are four important columns based on a 5%, 10%, 15% or "other" tip.

[image]

As you can see, sometimes a neat number will be prioritized. Or for 15,10€ you would take 10% and round down a little because it is rounded to 50 ct but is closer to 10%.

Obviously this is a subjective assessment but may be useful to foreigners to get a feel for what is the right amount. I found that e.g. people from the US tip too much. While no server will complain of course, you are "wasting" money and might come across as a show-off.

### What to say?

- If you don't say anything and just hand the server your money, they should give you the change to the cent. If they don't, this would be very rude and worth a complaint.
- If you want to tip, you just say the desired amount while you are handing him the money, e.g. *Achtzehn, bitte*. So, simply the amount followed by a "*Bitte*". He will give you change for the amount specified by you.
- If you have the desired amount handy, you just give him the 18 € and say "*Stimmt so!*" which informs the server that this is the correct amount you want to give and he does not have to give you anything back.

### Source

I have been living in Germany for 27+ years.

Comment: This answer only reflects your opinion (the amounts 'felt right') and does not go into the actual question: How much *should* someone tip in Germany.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo In the absence of a Bundestrinkgeldberechnungsverordnungsgesetz, the question is about individual opinions.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I don't think you can get anything better than that type of answer. I still think it is useful though. My hope is that other Germans will vote on the available answers and thus democratically determine what the social norm is.

Comment: Additional remark: The notes and coins you carry may influence what is "right". For a bill of 44€, if you have notes of 20€+20€+5€ and a 2€ coin, you might be ok even if that means less than 10%. But if you have to use a 50€ note, you would appear cheap if you asked to have 1€ or 2€ back, even if that would mean more tip than in the previous example ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Exactly, and that is why the question is off-topic here, since it does not have a right answer. This is a question-and-answer forum and not an opinion discussion forum.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I would argue that it is still useful and substnatially  different from "Where can I buy the best pizza?" or "What is the most beatiful city in the world?" type questions which this rule was made to prevent.

Comment: @problemofficer The rule was made to prevent open-ended questions with no single correct answer. Please go to the help center and read what's written there if you believe something else.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Imho its not as black and white. Only a minority of the questions on this site have one and only one correct answer. I think, it comes down to variance. While "favorite pizza" questions have almost unlimited answers, the variance for tips is relatively small and will cristalize by voting on answers. Also this is highly relevant to traveling. Finally, rules are made to codify principles and have no meaning in themselves. I am trying to argue why this question is useful for this site. Simply answering that it is against the rules ignoring its benefit is counterproductive imho.

Comment: @problemofficer I have not 'simply' said that the question is off-topic, but tried to explain why. As you can see in the other question, trying to answer how much is common to tip in Germany leeds to endless discussions and there simply is no right answer. Your answer is also not right. This site is for questions and answers. It is *not* and was never ment to be a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, 10% sounds good, often rounded to a "neat" value.

- If the bill is €17 or €17.50, one might pass an €20 note and say "Stimmt so." Literally translated it means "that's right as it is," indicating that one does not want any change.
- If the bill is €9.80, one might pass an €20 note and say "Auf elf." Literally "to eleven," this means one wants to pay €11 and get €9 back. (Possibly a northern idiom.)
- Passing money in a way that makes no sense if one expects change is an indication that one wants to tip. If the bill is €9.50 and one passes an €10 note plus an €2 coin, this indicates an €2.50 tip unless one says something like "Auf elf."
- Raising a hand as the waiter gets the change indicates that one wants no change. This can be a quite subtle gesture if the amount *looks* right for an included tip.

Comment: I have never witnessed the "pushing-away gesture" and would find it condecending tbh.

Comment: @problemofficer, the waiter starts to get the change, one raises one hand palm facing forward? Do you recognize that and how would you describe it?

Comment: I still find it condecending and I don't remeber ever seing it. Not saying anything, to me shows contempt towards the server because you don't even bother spending the energy to say two words.

Comment: Also, I never heard "auf..". Can I ask which region of Germany you are from?

Comment: @problemofficer, Lower Saxony, now living in Berlin.

Comment: I rather know "Machen Sie elf" (or just "elf")

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, where do you live? I would understand (but not use) "machen Sie es elf." Without *es* it sounds wrong.

Comment: A better translation for “Stimmt so” would be “That's right like that” or “It's OK as is”. “Stimmt” already means “That's right”.